# jQuery ui close on mouse click / escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi all I am using jQuery ui autocomplete and all works well except once activated and the drop down list appears, if the user hits "escape" or clicks away the list remains open.

Is there a setting I have missed. The code is below. Many thanks!

```
/*** Set up multiselect drop down lists ***/
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {

        _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( this.element );
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .val( value )    
                .attr( "title", "" ) 
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
                .tooltip({
                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                })
                .on('mouseup', function() {
                    $(this).select();
                });

                $(this).blur();             

                this._on( this.input, {
                  autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger( "select", event, {
                      item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function() {
            var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;

            $( "<a>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
            .tooltip()
            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
            .mousedown(function() {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
            })
            .click(function() {
                input.focus();
                input.blur();

                // Close if already visible
                if ( wasOpen ) { return; };

                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
            });
        },

        _source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
            response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                var text = $( this ).text();
                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }) );
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
                return;
            };

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var default_text = "";

            var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;

            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {

                if ( $( this ).val() == "default" ) {
                    default_text = $( this ).text();
                };

                if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                };
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
                return;
            };

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
                .val( default_text )
                .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                .tooltip( "open" );

            this._delay(function() {
                this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
            }, 2500 );
            this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        },

        refresh: function () {
            selected = this.element.children(":selected");
            this.input.val(selected.text());
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                item: ui.item.option
            });
            select.trigger("change");
        },

        _change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                    valid = false;
                select.children("option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                        this.selected = valid = true;
                        return false;
                    };
                });
                if (!valid) {
                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                    $(this).val("");
                    select.val("");
                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                    return false;
                };
            };
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: can you give fiddler for this

Comment: hi @rjdmello, thanks for the suggestion! It works fine in jsfiddle but not in my project. Still not sure why. Would you look at the site? I would have to give you a log in though. Thanks!

Comment: yes give me link will check it, before that i will ask to comment this code   .on('mouseup', function() {
                    $(this).select();
                });

                $(this).blur();

Comment: Hi @rjdmello, how do I give you a userid & pwd without publishing it here? You ROCK! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @rjdmello, commenting out the code you suggested made no difference. Thanks

Comment: solved it, I had an "input.blur();" that needed commenting out in the .click function inside of "_createShowAllButton:"

Answer (score 0):

Comment out `input.blur();` inside of `_createShowAllButton`.

```
    _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
            wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
        .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
        .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo( this.wrapper )
        .button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        })
        .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
        .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
        .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
        })
        .click(function() {
            input.focus();
        //      input.blur();    <-- COMMENT THIS OUT / REMOVE

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) { return; };

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
        });
    },
```